# What is the difference between UIAutomator and UIAutomator2. Why should I switch to UIAutomator2?

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

I am currently using UIAutomator2, but I am not sure what other capabilities it gives on top of UIAutomator. I am using Appium with UIAutomator2 and face no challenges, but want to leverage some new features introduced in UIAutomator2, if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UiAutomator2 is a custom implementation of Google UiAutomator by Appium community, that mostly fixes existing issues in original UiAutomator and stabilise/speedup interactions with UI elements: from my own measurement tests running Android 6/UiAutomator 2 are in average **20-30%** faster then the same ones on Android 5.1/UiAutomator

Starting with *Android 6* Appium supports **UiAutomator2 only**, so basically there is no choice to go with old flaky UiAutomator and community do not support it, so if smth doesn't work with UiAutomator -> its up to you to solve it.

There not to much custom features actually, but you may try and use [some of capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md) and for sure read [release notes](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases) of appium as they usually display whats new in recent UiAutomator2 release, e.g. `Speed up screenshot logic in UiAutomator2`